# What were the founding fathers' views on Native Americans?

Tags: united-states, native-americans, constitution, founding-fathers

What were the founding fathers' views on Native Americans?

Did the founding fathers have a lack of respect for the natives, or were they accounted for positively in the enacting of the constitution? Are there any personally written anecdotes from them showing a particular opinion?

Comment: This question would benefit from some [preliminary research](http://nativeamericannetroots.net/diary/1077).

Comment: They didn't have any, of course, since "Native American" is a piece of political correctness that didn't come along until a couple of centuries later.  But I don't think you will find any consistent view of the Indians shared by the "Founding Fathers".  It would also help if you specified just who you'd like to include in that group: the signatories to the Declaration of Independence, the authors of the Constitution, anyone politically active in Revolutionary times?

Comment: They weren't accounted for at all in the Constitution.  That document was for citizens of the US, which at the time did not include members of the tribes adjacent to areas the US government controlled.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Indians were mentioned twice in the Constitution: "Indians not taxed" are not to be counted in apportioning seats in the House of Representatives, and the power to regulate interstate commerce includes commerce with the Indian Tribes. They are also mentioned, unfavorably, in the Declaration of Independence.

Answer (score 6):

I think we can adress one issue rather easily, concerning

> Did the founding fathers have a lack of respect for the natives

A very simple answer would be to look at how relations with the Native American Tribes were handled: [Treaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty).

from [here](http://www.mountvernon.org/digital-encyclopedia/article/native-american-policy/):

> In referring to the constitutional grant of treaty-making powers to
>   the chief executive—with the "advice and consent" of the
>   Senate—**Washington declared that a similar practice should also apply
>   to agreements with Native Americans**. The Senate acceded to the
>   President's wishes and accepted treaties as the basis for conducting
>   Indian relations.
>
> In response, Congress proceeded to approve a treaty with seven
>   northern tribes (the Shawnee, Miami, Ottawa, Chippewa, Iroquois, Sauk,
>   and Fox).

Another [site here](http://nativeamericannetroots.net/diary/1077) discussing some of these treaty negotiations:

> Alexander McGillivray and 26 other Creek chiefs signed a treaty with
>   President George Washington in New York. While Washington did not love
>   Indians, he treated the Creek delegation to dinners, parades, and
>   diplomatic ceremonies ***that equaled, and some say exceeded, those
>   accorded to any European diplomatic mission***.

So is the founding fathers opinion concerning treatment or respect for Native Americans written, yes, as law.  They determined to treat them with the respect due any Nation, by conducting treaties in the same fashions as those with the European powers of the day.